# Change Default Framework List of a Xcode Project (Link Binary With Libraries)

Tags: xcode, frameworks, xcode6

I am creating so many new projects on Xcode in a day. I got tired of putting necessary frameworks for each project every time.

So can we change the **default framework list** in Build Phases -> **Link Binary With Libraries**?

If it is possible, can we also add frameworks to that **default framework list** from outside of Xcode?

For example:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a direct solution to edit default framework list of Xcode, but a temporary solution that I found is to edit Search Paths under Build Settings

[image]